# Elastic Search - how to make 'select in'

Tags: elasticsearch

### self solved. :)

I made elastic search mapped which has nested fields.

fields are like below

```
id
name (nested field)
```

and Data are like

```
id   name
1    jone
1    jack
2    jane
2    kim
3    lee
3    park
```

I would like to get names that parents has jone.
It's like `select name from table where id in ( select id from table where name ='jone')` in sql.

My expect result is jone and jack.

It it able to make query in elastic search?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregation on the field name to get all distinct name:

```
"query":{
    "term":{
        "id" : 1
    }   
},
"size":0,
"aggregations":{
    "group_by_name":{
        "terms": {
            "field": "name"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is like '... where id=1', not ''' where id in (select ...' .
I cannot predict of id fields value, that's why I need 'select in'.